# Want to get the mouse coordinate in a while loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, click, mouse, coordinate

I would like to get the mouse click coordinate for several images. This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

j = 0
while j < nb_images:
    plt.ion()
    fig = plt.figure()
    coords = []
    #Affichage
    plt.imshow(img[j], cmap="gray")
    plt.draw()

    while len(coords) <1:
        cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

    print(coords[0][0], coords[0][1])
j = j + 1

def onclick(event):
    global ix, iy
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    global coords
    coords.append((ix, iy))
    if len(coords) == 1:
        fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
        plt.close()
    return coords
```

The problem is that I cannot click on the figure to get the coordinate. The figure is busy. How I can fix it?
Thank you

Comment: the imports are missing, the example is not complete. Which graphical framework are you using?

Comment: Yes, this is a part of the code. I used import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Comment: just seen an unindented `j = j+1` statement. If it's like that, that's normal that it locks up: infinite loop, condition never reached.

Comment: Please fix indentation. It cannot be correct or there would have been an array out of bounds on `img[j]`

Comment: When I indent the line j = j + 1, the image are displayed all together . Howerver I would like to do the following step for each image (i.e. for each "j") : 1) display the figure 2) click on the figure 3) get the coordinates. And only after that I move to the next image to do the sames steps

Comment: in that case you have to invoke an event loop somewhere.

Comment: How? I have already used canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

Comment: seems that you' re not getting how a GUI system works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to answer, although I cannot test, being unable to get hold of mathplotlib on windows, so I'm sure it does not work as is but at least it corrects the way to create things & callbacks.

The posted code had many flaws:

- it relied on an interactive way of doing things. Mathplotlib defines callback and has a mainloop (`plt.show()` that need to be called
- there is an infinite loop because j increase was outside the `while` loop. I simplified the loop with a `for`
- all actions shall be performed in the `onclick` callback.

Feel free to edit

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
i = 0

def onclick(event):
    global ix, iy, i
    ix, iy = event.xdata, event.ydata
    global coords
    coords.append((ix, iy))
    print("clicked "+str(coords))
    i+=1
    if i == nb_images:
         plt.close()
         fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
         # then do something with the coords array
    else:
         # show next image and go one
         plt.imshow(img[i], cmap="gray")

plt.ion()
fig = plt.figure()

plt.imshow(img[0], cmap="gray")


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

Comment: No, in that way all the images are displayed in one time. I would like to displayed on by one... I have more than one hundred images

Comment: ok, I was suspecting that. I'll try to update the answer. Remember I don't have mathplotlib to test.